# Angular Universal selective rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Can I chose certain paths to not be server-side rendered when running an Angular app with Angular Universal?

The default server.ts file that is generated:

```
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // TODO: implement data requests securely
  server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not yet supported');
  });

  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}
```

Can I add a rule for a certain path to be served like it would be in a regular `ng serve`?

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy such as nginx or apache?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! No, I'm not using a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the `index.html` file straight to the client for selected routes

```
//No prerendering for /about and /contact
//Note that these routes must be defined before the '*' generic route
app.get('/contact|/about', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(distFolder, 'index.html'));
});

// All other regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
 });
```